# Factory does not return value from provider after Angular update

Tags: angular, factory, angular12, angular-providers, angular-upgrade

In app.module.ts has the following provider:

```
{
    provide: LOCALE_ID,
    useFactory: (translate: TranslateService) => translate.currentLang,
    deps: [TranslateService]
}
```

I have updated angular version from 8.2 (iteratively to 12).
Everything worked on version 8.2, but now **undefined is always written to LOCALE_ID**.

But if I change the code to:

```
{
    provide: LOCALE_ID,
    useValue: 'en'
}
```

Then everything works, from here I conclude that the problem in useFactory, but there are no ideas how to fix it.

---

*Additionally, if it is important:*

1. I am using ngx-translate 13.0.0
2. In services and pipes, I get the parameter as follows:

```
constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale: string)
```

3. Also TranslateService is undefined in the AppModule class, although in other places of the application, after loading it is available

---

**SOLVED:**
The question was solved, the transfer of the provider from app.module to app.component helped

Comment: If you solved your issue, you can self-answer and accept it to share how you fix it.

Comment: Please post an answer so that we can tell that is is solved without having to load the page. Thanks. Glad you worked it out.